# storing config / option data in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

What would be an good way of storing application options in a neo4j database? 
I have few settings that I would like to persist for an application.

In an SQL database, I would create a table with 2 columns (name and value) (and perhaps a few more, but you get the idea).

In neo4j I'm thinking about a single node (with a 'Config' Label) and have an attribute for each setting I want to store.

Is this a recommended way of doing this? Feels kind of strange for a graph database, since this node will not have any relationship.

Comment: Will your graph consist only of that one node? If not, what are some other examples of data in the graph?

Comment: No, there are other Nodes and relations in the database. These config options are like global data, They are not conected to the other Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a perfectly fine way to do what you want.